# Show/Hide UINavigationBar with animated screen move like in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have UITextView on the sreen and UINavigationBar on top of it.
How can i achieve effect like when in touching UISearchBar. Is it possible?

Comment: can u tell me what do you want exactly..?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much with a `UISearchBar` inside of 
  `-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` you'd use  `[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES]` which animates it to hide when you  click inside of the search bar, then inside of `- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` you'd use `[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated:YES]` which animates it returning into the view.

In the `UITextView`'s Delegate you get two methods that are essentially the same.

`- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

Where you would put
`[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES]`

`- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

Where you would put
`[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated:YES]`